# Rear derailleur cable housing length

Tags: derailleur-rear, cable

I've cut my first cable housing using [this ParkTool page](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/housing-length) as a guide. The thing is, I think it's a bit too long. Can I safely shorten it or the length is good as it is now?

[image: cut 1]

**Update:** 7.5cm less, is it better now?

[image: cut 2]

Comment: no, I'd definitely shorten that. Easy enough to do, just make sure you use cutters designed for gear cable (as opposed to brake cable)

Comment: There's no great harm from having it too long -- better that than too short.  The biggest hazard it that it will get hung up in racks, etc.  That said, I'd advise shortening it by 3-4 inches.

Comment: Yeah, that can be shortened by a lot.

Comment: "cutters designed for gear cable as opposed to brake cable?" ??? Both shimano and park only sell a single cutter for cable AND housing, e.g., http://www.parktool.com/product/professional-cable-and-housing-cutter-cn-10

Comment: This one's definitely too long. It makes the shifting less precise. Put the chain on the smallest cog and shorten the housing so that your hand fits easily between cogs and housing. You'll need three hands for that! ;)

Comment: @ChrisCleeland that may be the case, but different outer cables (spiral or linear) should ideally be cut with different cutters (side or cross) so as to achieve a clean cut

Comment: I see.  You are referring to housing and not cable, @PeteH. Regardless, I cannot find a different cutter available from Park, Pedros, Hozan, Campagnolo, or Shimano. Can you refer me to one of these different cutters?

Comment: You can also cut housing with rotary tool, just be careful not to overheat inner liner or it will melt.

Comment: [Side Cutters](http://www.webbline.co.uk/store/p62/Side_%E2%80%98Piano_Wire%E2%80%99_Cutters.html) / [Cross Cutters](http://www.webbline.co.uk/store/p52/Wire_Cutters.html)

Comment: The cable still looks a hair long, but not unreasonable.

Comment: The cutting action on this is the same as shimano or park cutters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too long, and it may get into the spokes.Roughly, you can cut the 1/3 of the current cable housing.

Answer (score 2):

It's too long, and you should cut it again to get it closer to the right length.  As a guideline, you could look at pictures of similar bikes online and cut you own cable housing so that the curve ends up about the same.

- If it's too short, the curve is too tight, and that adds friction.
- If it's too long, it adds a bit of friction, and you can get things caught in it when you ride.